# When is it possible to reclaim land in Freeciv by transforming ocean and lake tiles into swamp?

Tags: freeciv

It is possible to do land reclamation by placing a ship containing engineers on an ocean or lake tile, and then ordering those engineers to transform the tile into swamp.

However, I have noticed that not all water tiles can be transformed into swamp. Sometimes the transform to swamp button for the engineers is blanked out. From experience, only some ocean/lake tiles next to a land tile can be transformed; it is not possible to transform an ocean tile in the middle of a vast ocean into land.

What are the exact conditions under which an ocean or lake tile can be transformed into swamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terrain transformation requires the following two conditions to be met:

1. The tile is surrounded by at least N land tiles.

The number N is determined by the current game's **ruleset**, specifically the option `ocean_reclaim_requirement = 30%`. By default, since the game defines that each tile borders 8 other tiles, this is equivalent to needing 3 adjacent land tiles. In order to transform an arbitrary tile in the middle of the ocean, you would need to transform at the minimum a 3-tile wide *bridge* of tiles towards it, for example in a pattern like this:

[image: Technique to polderize an ocean]

2. The tile needs to not be in the *permafrost region* of the map. These are any tiles that are frozen at the start of the game. So snow or ice tiles.

There's another map parameter `thaw_requirement` that sets this. By default the value is 101, which does not allow thawing or freezing tiles via terraforming.

Also see [the relevant wiki page](https://freeciv.fandom.com/wiki/Terrain#Later_improvements), or browse the code over at [github](https://github.com/freeciv/freeciv): the relevant section is the function [`terrain_surroundings_allow_change`](https://github.com/freeciv/freeciv/blob/R2_6_2/common/map.c#L722-L752) in `/common/map.c`, and the function [`can_reclaim_ocean`](https://github.com/freeciv/freeciv/blob/R2_6_2/common/map.c#L671-L682).

Comment: What software did you use to create the figure?

Comment: @Flux It's just a screenshot of a spreadsheet, using 'no borders' and centered text.

Comment: Regarding "the tile needs to not be in the permafrost region of the map": are you sure about this? I used to transform the entire polar region into plains and grassland.

Comment: @Flux I'm quite sure. The default value for thaw_requirement (percentage of non-freezing tiles around a frozen tile that's needed to be able to thaw it) is 101% (never). I suppose you could make your own modded terrain.ruleset file (see https://freeciv.fandom.com/wiki/Editing_Terrain). I don't think you can easily do this for a game that's already in progress though.